# <svg/> element does not respect 100% height/width in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

`<svg></svg>`

http://jsfiddle.net/c6SW6/

It works correctly in Chrome but I cannot seem to get the svg element to fully expand no matter what I try.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The SVGSVGElement does not support a percent value for the width attribute, although most browsers support it nonetheless. There's a lot of controversy on this [subject](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2013/04/13/svg-spec-missing-documentation-the-viewport-and-svg-width/).

Comment: I wouldn't pay any attention to that article, it's almost entirely wrong. Percentage widths are allowed as attributes on an outer SVG element per the SVG specification for instance and no implementors that I know of (and I'm one of them) dispute that. The second part, entitled SVG viewport references the section in the SVG specification about embedding SVG in HTML but the author doesn't seem to realise that that's what it's about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give `html` a height of 100% as well:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6SW6/1/)

Comment: That makes sense... but can you make it work with absolute positioning? It works if you change the tag to a div.  http://jsfiddle.net/c6SW6/2/  http://jsfiddle.net/c6SW6/3/

Comment: Weird. It's broken for me in FF 21 and 17.0.5 but if I put the SVG at 100% in an absolutely positioned div I can achieve what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jbrown:  That's strange.  Have you tried supplying a source to the SVG object?

Comment: I'm using d3.js to programmatically draw graphs. I tested to see if it resized after I added a node but no luck.

Comment: firefox drunks with svg